# formula for Brunét's index

Tags: computational-linguistics, semantics, lexical-semantics

I am having trouble figuring out the formula for Brunet's index which can be found in this paper http://csbapp.uncw.edu/data/mscsis/annalspaper.aspx?v=6&i=1&p=11.

I tried to apply it to interviews with ~1000 words, however, the values generated seems to be very extreme around e-100. Is this statistic not valid for large text?

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of **N** and **V**? Are you sure that this is really the correct definition (go back to the original publication, don't rely on the paper in the link)? I tried a google book search, but some relevant pages were hidden, therefore only comments, no answer.

Comment: My appologies, N in this case is the number of word token within the text and V is the word type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the formula was actually BI = N^V^(-.165) which returned more reasonable values.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so this no longer comes up as unanswered. Thanks.